# Creating a search bar using Laravel and Vue JS (Vuetify Framework) - resulting in error 'Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, search, axios, vuetify.js

I'm coding a search bar using Laravel and Vue JS (more specifically the Vuetify framework). My controller functions:

```
/**
 * Get the names and references of all projects for the user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function getAllProjects()
{
    return Project::forClient()->get(['name','reference']);
}

/**
 * Query the names and references of all projects for the user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function searchForProject(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->query('query');

    $projects = Project::where('name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->orWhere('reference', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->get();

    return view('projects.edit', compact('projects'));
}
```

Search bar in Vue:

```
        <v-autocomplete
        v-model="model"
        :items="getProjNames"
        :loading="isLoading"
        clearable
        hide-details
        @keyup.enter="queryForProjects()"
        item-text="name"
        item-value="symbol"
        solo
        >
            <template v-slot:no-data>
                <v-list-item>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                        Please search for a project
                    </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
            </template>
        </v-autocomplete>
```

Methods:

```
    getAllProjects() {
        var self = this;
        apiClient.get(window.routes["projects.getAllProjects"])
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                self.projects = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.error(error);
                if (!!error.response) console.log(error.response);
            });
    },

    queryForProjects() {
        var self = this;
        apiClient.post(window.routes["projects.searchForProject"], {query: this.model})
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                self.projects = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.error(error);
                if (!!error.response) console.log(error.response);
            });
    },
```

Computed value to list all projects:

```
computed: {
    getProjNames() {
        return this.projects.map(a => a.name);
    }
},
```

However, I keep getting the following error which tells me that (I think), something isn't correct in the request, however I'm unsure as to what is actually wrong:

[image]

Comment: In your code I don't get any `protocol`

Answer (score 0):

This error message is telling you that somewhere in your javascript code you are referencing a protocol attribute on an object which does not exist. It looks like whatever code this is has not been included in the post.

You need to find that reference, e.g. request.protocol or meeting.protocol. Then, look for where the object (request or meeting in these examples) comes from specific to the context, and ensure it is loaded and/or passed correctly.

If you need further help, you will need to post the code which references [something].protocol and it's full context.

Hope this helps!